# Bundle data for pyinstaller error (--onefile)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to include an image for my .exe. I'm following the directions as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile). It says the build completes successfully in terminal. When I run the .exe it marks a fatal error in the program.

Any ideas appreciated.

My directory looks like

```
/Box Tracking
--/res
----amazon_box.jpg
--main.py
--gui.py
```

Related code from gui.py:

```python
import tkinter as tk
import main
import traceback
import time
import random
# use these libs since base tkinter can only open gif and other obscure formats
# must install Pillow rather than PIL
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from jokes import jokes
import sys, os # these will allow me to bundle the image in the distro

def resource_path(relative_path):
    '''
    See notes
    :param relative_path: path I will use | string | 'res/amazon-box.jpg'
    :return: string | path
    '''
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)

root = tk.Tk()  # create GUI instance
root.geometry("1000x1000") # make GUI big so that users can see it
root.title('Box Tracking') # name GUI

# add a background so users can see it
bg_image = Image.open(resource_path('res/amazon-box.jpg'))
tk_bg_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bg_image)
bg = tk.Label(root,image=tk_bg_image)
bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
```

Snippet I use to build the .exe:
`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data res/amazon-box.jpg;. --name "Box Tracking 3.1.5" gui.py`

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but I do it this way:

In the `\res\` directory I'd have `amazon_box.py` and an empty `__init__.py`

You can convert an image to a base64 using a small script such as:

```
import base64
with open("amazon_box.jpg", "rb") as image:
    b = base64.b64encode(image.read())
with open("amazon_box.py", "w") as write_file:
    write_file.write("def photo(): return (" + str(b) + ")"
```

in `amazon_box.py` it will have (automatically created by the above script):

```
def photo(): return (image_as_base64)
```

After that the image can be used in the main script with `PhotoImage(data = )`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from res import amazon_box

root = tk.Tk()  # create GUI instance

root.geometry("1000x1000") # make GUI big so that users can see it
root.title('Box Tracking') # name GUI

# add a background so users can see it
tk_bg_image = tk.PhotoImage(data = amazon_box.photo())
bg = tk.Label(root,image=tk_bg_image)
bg.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
```

Obviously I haven't tested it with your image, but this is how I've wrapped images into onefiles in the past, and you can have multiple images in the one `.py` file, so it actually can be a pretty clean end result.

**Edit:**

Since it's just another module to PyInstaller at this point, my build command is the standard: `pyinstaller.exe --windowed --onefile "path\to\main\py\file"`

I usually just run PyInstaller from command prompt.

Comment: @ChristinaZhou Actually I'm glad I looked back into this more, I've found, if encoded properly, `tempfile` is not needed and `tk.PhotoImage` can load most base64 encoded images directly.